# Parts of Deal Annotation Not Showing in Gmail Promotions Tab

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

My team has been testing using deal annotations on marketing emails, but we're having issues getting the full annotation to display in the Promotions tab.

When testing with the preview tool, everything shows as expected. However when the email is sent, the offer description shows, but the other fields (discount code/end date) are not displayed.

For troubleshooting, we created a promotabtesting email address for testing, have confirmed all settings are correct, and are using the latest version of Gmail. We also have confirmed that the script tags are not getting stripped by putting the code of the sent email into the preview tool.

Here is an example of one of the annotations we've tried (x'd out details for privacy):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
      [{
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "DiscountOffer",
        "description": "$200 in xxxxx",
        "discountCode": "xxxBONUS"
      }]
    </script>
```

Any ideas on how we can get the full annotation to display would be greatly appreciated!